# Kendo PanelBarItem add custom component as child

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I wanted to create component, template of which contains PanelBarItems.

It does not seem to work.
Any ideas why?

**Main Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <kendo-panelbar>
    <app-sub></app-sub>
  </kendo-panelbar>`
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

**Child Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub',
  template: '<kendo-panelbar-item title="test"></kendo-panelbar-item>'
})
export class SubComponent {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only [PanelBarItem components](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/PanelBarItemComponent/) can be directly nested and rendered within a Kendo PanelBar component. If you want to build a reusable component and use it within the PanelBar, you can do so by providing it as content of the panel bar items by wrapping it in a **ng-template** tag with the [kendoPanelBarContent directive](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/api/PanelBarContentDirective/), e.g.:

```
<kendo-panelbar>
        <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="'My Teammates'" expanded="true">
            <ng-template kendoPanelBarContent>
                <custom-component></custom-component>
                <app-sub></app-sub>...
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SPO4ZMhfNQFm7du8w1xT?p=preview

Comment: I was having problems adding nested panelbar-items from objectArray, your example realy helped me out. thanks!